# Rename file in directory (Shelljs)

Tags: shelljs

How can i rename a file into the same directory?

When i run this i've got the following error:

`shell.cp('-R', './../../config/test.txt', './../../config/test1.txt');`

- cp: dest is not a directory (too many sources)

I read the docs, but none of that answers my question.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilize the ShellJS [`mv()`](https://documentup.com/shelljs/shelljs#mvoptions--source--source--dest) command to rename a file instead of the `cp()` command.

Assuming that the path definitions in your given example actually do exist, utilize the following instead:

```js
var shell = require('shelljs');

shell.mv('./../../config/test.txt', './../../config/test1.txt');
```

---

**Note:** The `./` part at the beginning of each of the pathnames that you've provided seems to be redundant so you can omit that part too. For instance:

```js
var shell = require('shelljs');

shell.mv('../../config/test.txt', '../../config/test1.txt');
```